# Connection speed required for webhosting server

Tags: web-hosting, connection, network-speed

I'm interested how to calculate required speed for and connection that will be used for webhosting server?

e.g. I have a server with around 300 websites ( they  do not have large traffic on them). 
I'v checked bandwidth for the pas year and it's always around 300GB per month.   Would connection of 5Mb up and 5Mb down  be enough for this server?

Thank you

Comment: 300 websites, "not large traffic"? These are useless numbers. Bandwidth per month is also only interesting when it comes to paying for it. What you should be interested in are the peaks. That's the load you have to handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

5 Mbits/s will be enough for your server. 1 Mbit will burst out 324 GB if used 24 hours a day per month.

In the rush hours (between 09:00 to 17:00) 1 Mbit connection can use about 120 GB/Mo.
so 5 will be much higher i.e.:120x5 = 600 GB/Mo